# Restringir sobrescrita de método de um objeto no javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, objetos

Estou tentando criar um objeto onde os seus métodos não possam ser alterados. Ou seja, o seu valor, mesmo que alterado, deverá continuar como o definido inicialmente.

Exemplo:

```
var object = (function(object){

      object.method = function (text) {
          return 'response ' + text + '!!!';
      }

})({});
```

eu posso acessá-lo da seguinte forma:

```
object.method()
```

Porém é possível alterar o método, simplesmente fazendo isso:

```
 object.method = null
 //TypeError: object is not a function
```

Já no `jQuery`, quando fazemos essa tentativa de alteração, o método html continua fazendo a mesma coisa para o qual foi projetado.

```
$('body').html = null
$('body').html() // funciona normalmente
```

A não ser que você salve o valor de `$('body')` numa variável:

```
$body = $('body');
$body.html = null;
////TypeError: object is not a function
```

No primeiro exemplo utilizado com `jQuery`, como é que ele internamente faz para manter os métodos intactos? Ele sempre cria uma nova instância?

Como bloquear a reescrita dos métodos de um objeto?

Comment: Restringir não tem jeito, até porque o jQuery não protege nada, você continua podendo fazer o que quiser com JS puro. Se você usar certo o recurso ele te ajuda a não fazer besteira. O que você pode fazer é criar formas para te ajudar não fazer besteira, mas se você quiser, vai poder.

Comment: @bignow, me lembrei de um cara chamado `Object.freeze`. Será que ele resolver o problema?

Comment: Para o que você está dizendo, não. Ele só previne que a estrutura do objeto seja modificada. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

Comment: `Object.freeze` e `Object.seal` são opções que o ECMA5 possibilita, mas há alternativas. Vou dar uma olhada aqui mais logo a ver o que já foi dito. Boa pergunta.

Comment: Dei uma resposta, mas pelos comentários acima acho que posso ter entendido mal a pergunta... Você quer saber como evitar que uma propriedade/método de um objeto seja alterada, ou quer saber como o jQuery funciona? Deixei uma nota sobre isso no final da minha resposta, mas se quiser posso elaborar mais...

Comment: @mgibsonbr eu só sei que alguém entendeu mal, quem eu não arriscaria :) De qualquer forma a resposta é boa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode utilizar [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) de modo a ter maior controle sobre as características do seu método (ou campo). Por exemplo, para tornar seu método somente-leitura, atribua `writable` como `false`:

```js
var object = (function(object){

      Object.defineProperty(object, 'method', {
          value:function (text) {
              return 'response ' + text + '!!!';
          },
          writable:false
      });
  
      return object;

})({});

document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML += object.method("teste") + "<br>";

// Não tem nenhum efeito (mas não lança nenhuma exceção!)
object.method = function() {
    return "Tentando mudar o método";
};

// Ainda chama o método antigo
document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML += object.method("teste");
```

```html
<p id="saida"></p>
```

P.S. O caso do jQuery que você mencionou se comporta dessa forma porque o objeto retornado por `$(...)` não é o mesmo em uma invocação e em outra:

```
var a = $('body');
var b = $('body');
a == b; // false
```

Além disso, se você substituir um método em `$.fn` ele passa a valer para todos os objetos criados a partir de `$(...)`:

```
$.fn.html = function() {
    alert("Método alterado!");
};

$('body').html(); // Chama o método sobrescrito
```

Comment: Esse `$.fn` é a mesma coisa que `$.prototype`, não é?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Acho que não (mas não tenho certeza). Acredito que `$.prototype` seria o protótipo de qualquer objeto criado com `new $(...)`, mas nunca vi código nenhum fazer isso dessa forma. Já `$.fn` define propriedades a qualquer objeto criado via `$(...)`, mas não sei se isso é implementado internamente como protótipo ou como *mixin*. Teria de consultar os fontes do jQuery pra ter certeza.

Comment: É porque no código-fonte do jquery já vi um paranauê assim: `jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype ... `. Por isso pensei que fosse :)

Comment: Você tem razão! Quando se chama `$(...)` o que ocorre por baixo dos panos é um `new jQuery.fn.init(...)`, de modo que o protótipo do objeto retornado é o `init.prototype`. Entretanto, em uma outra parte do fonte vejo que `init.prototype = jQuery.fn;` e, como `fn` é igual ao `prototype`, então `new $(...)` deve ter o mesmo resultado prático de `$(...)`. É confuso, mas de todo modo sua afirmação está correta, ambos são a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 0):

Porque quando você faz:

```
$('body').html = null
$('body').html()
```

Você está chamando a função $ separadamente então vai retornar sempre um objeto separado.

Comment: Mas como fazer para não permitir a sobrescrita dos métodos?

Comment: Por que o voto negativo? Essa resposta está incompleta, mas está correta (ela explica o porque da sobrescrita em um objeto não afetar o outro objeto)

Comment: Não fui eu que deu o voto negativo, mas talvez que deu pensou que estivesse falando da mesma coisa que já está relatada na pergunta. Foi o que eu pensei quando vi, por isso não dei +1